# Turn off HyperThreading without BIOS

Tags: virtual-machine, performance, cpu, bios, hyper-threading

I need to turn off HyperThreading from my i5-3210 notebook since it hinders my IDE performance. My i3 took about 10+ seconds from compile to run in my Android VM, same code runs in my AMD in about 10 seconds, while it took about 6 minutes in i5.

I am sure the problem lies on i5's HyperThreading, because I noticed that all 4 logical cores stayed at 100% for more than 5 minutes while it was loading VM while compiling my code. At that times, even mouse cursor stuttered, Youtube stopped playing video, and audio stuttered. After compiling done, then all 4 fluctuated wildly for another 1-2 minutes when VM loaded and started my code.

The VM is HAXM running Android 6, and also VirtualBox with GenyMotion. IDE is Android Studio, Virtualization has been enabled, my notebook is ASUS A55V, and I've tried to look in bios to turn it off but couldn't find it. I also don't want to restrict it to one core since I need to run them on multiple cores using affinity. And I am sure that I need to see my code performance in multiple cores. So, restricting using affinity like many people suggested is not acceptable solution.

Any one has any suggestion on how to disable 1 logical core in each cores? Can it be done? Or any other suggestion?

Thank you

Comment: I can't help but thinkg that are you misdiagnosing the issue. Instead, if you want to disable the IDEs access to additional cores for build. In visual studio this option is under Tools -> Options -> Projects and Solutions -> Build and run -> "maximum number of parallel project builds".

Comment: It is Android Studio. I tried to put it in tags but was not allowed

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am going to be honest, I am not familiar with the Intel HAXM, but you might be able to throttle it to use less resources.  If that does have a setting you may want to look in the Android Studio configuration:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19986498/android-studio-using-100-cpu-at-all-times-no-background-processes-appear-to

This thread mentions a program call Process Lasso which worked well for them:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31350847/android-studio-using-100-cpu-on-an-i7-processor-for-project-rebuild

Comment: Thank you... so they confirmed my suspicions that using full threads on Intel i5 and i7 processors would slow down Android Studio significantly. I've downloaded Process Lasso. It is down to less than 10 seconds now. Love it.

Comment: BTW, Intel HAXM is Intel's Hypervisor for Android. It is installed as part of Android SDK to test project. Much like Virtual Box.